# Joomla 2.5 open view in modal window to add data

Tags: view, modal-dialog, joomla2.5

The goal should be following:
I have an edit view with a custom field (dropdown) that depends on another table. There I can choose from a list of adresses (the second table) to save the id of the data row. I started with this:

Custom field code:

```
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
class JFormFieldInvoiceAdress extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected $type = 'invoiceadress';
    protected function getInput() {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id,zip,city,adress');
        $query->from('#__pb_invoiceadresses');
        $db->setQuery((string)$query);
        $types = $db->loadObjectList();
        $options = array();
        foreach($types as $type) {
        $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $type->id, $type->zip . " " . $type->city . ", " .$type->adress);
        }
        $dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, $this->name, 'class="inputbox"', 'value', 'text', $this->value);
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=invoiceadresseedit&layout=edit&id=0';
        $dropdown .= "<a href=\"" . JRoute::_($link) . "\" class=\"modal\" rel=\"{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 875, y: 550}, onClose: function() {}}\" >Neue Adresse</a>";                      
        return $dropdown ;
    }
}
```

This works so far but I have to update the content of the dropdown on closing this modal window and not getting the list view of the invoiceadresses in the modal window.

My second attempt was to add 'tmpl=component' in the link but then I don't have a save button. I have no idea how to accomplish that. Anyone have already solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and I am answering it for the next person who comes along with the same question.

Call the edit view with this link:

```
$link = 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=invoiceadresseedit&layout=edit&id=0&tmpl=component';
```

This will display only the form without the rest of the administration gui and toolbar.

Add a save button to your edit form like this:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="<?php echo JText::_('SAVE');?>"  onClick="window.parent.location.reload();" />
```

And thats it. The data will be saved and after this the modal windows closes and the current page reloads, the dropdown will be updated with the new data.